# Access the source code of a webpage with a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, xpath, bookmarklet

I want to take a string (an ID number) from the source code of a webpage and load a new (replace the current) web page using the ID.

In the source code of web page A there is a tag

```
<meta name="navId" content="123">
```

I want to extract 123 and then load the URL

```
https://example.com/data?id=123
```

Can this be done using a bookmarklet?

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one `META` tag, this might work: 
`javascript:location.replace('https://example.com/data?id=' + document.getElementsByTagName("META")[0].content)`

Try changing the `[0]` to `[1]` if it's consistently the second META tag.